# Shell read *sometimes* strips trailing delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, sh

To parse colon-delimited fields I can use `read` with a custom `IFS`:

```
$ echo 'foo.c:41:switch (color) {' | { IFS=: read file line text && echo "$file | $line | $text"; }
foo.c | 41 | switch (color) {
```

If the last field contains colons, no problem, the colons are retained.

```
$ echo 'foo.c:42:case RED: //alert' | { IFS=: read file line text && echo "$file | $line | $text"; }
foo.c | 42 | case RED: //alert
```

A trailing delimiter is also retained...

```
$ echo 'foo.c:42:case RED: //alert:' | { IFS=: read file line text && echo "$file | $line | $text"; }
foo.c | 42 | case RED: //alert:
```

...Unless it's the *only* extra delimiter. Then it's stripped. **Wait, what?**

```
$ echo 'foo.c:42:case RED:' | { IFS=: read file line text && echo "$file | $line | $text"; }
foo.c | 42 | case RED
```

Bash, ksh93, and dash all do this, so I'm guessing it is POSIX standard behavior.

1. Why does it happen?
2. What's the best alternative?

I want to parse the strings above into three variables and I don't want to mangle any text in the third field. I had thought `read` was the way to go but now I'm reconsidering.

Comment: [Stéphane Chazelas's answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line/209184#209184) answers part of my first question, though I'm still unclear on whether this behavior is sensible or is merely an ugly historical wart.

Comment: I don't see anything in the [spec for `read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) that indicates a trailing field delimiter should  be removed.

Comment: You can proactively append comments containing a `:` to your code.

Comment: Looking at the bash source code `builtins/read.def` I found the following comment:  *Posix.2 says that the last variable gets the
     remaining words and their intervening separators.*  This is just before a conditional containing the call to the function `strip_trailing_ifs_whitespace`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's standard behaviour (see the [`read` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) and [Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05)). A few shells (`ash`-based including `dash`, `pdksh`-based, `zsh`, `yash` at least) used not to do it, but except for `zsh` (when not in POSIX mode), `busybox` sh, most of them have been updated for POSIX compliance.

That's the same for:

```
$ var='a:b:c:' IFS=:
$ set -- $var; echo "$#"
3
```

(see how the POSIX specification for `read` actually defers to the *Field Splitting* mechanism where `a:b:c:` is split into 3 fields, and so with `IFS=: read -r a b c`, there are as many fields as variables).

The rationale is that in `ksh` (on which the POSIX spec is based) `$IFS` (initially in the Bourne shell the *internal field separator*) became a *field  delimiter*, I think so any list of elements (not containing the delimiter) could be represented.

When `$IFS` is a *separator*, one can't represent a list of one empty element (`""` is split into a list of 0 element, `":"` into a list of two empty elements¹). When it's a *delimiter*, you can express a list of zero element with `""`, or one empty element with `":"`, or two empty elements with `"::"`.

It's a bit unfortunate as one of the most common usages of `$IFS` is to split `$PATH`. And a `$PATH` like `/bin:/usr/bin:` is meant to be split into `"/bin"`, `"/usr/bin"`, `""`, not just `"/bin"` and `"/usr/bin"`.

Now, with POSIX shells (but not all shells are compliant in that regard), for word splitting upon parameter expansion, that can be worked around with:

```
IFS=:; set -o noglob
for dir in $PATH""; do
  something with "${dir:-.}"
done
```

That  trailing `""` makes sure that if `$PATH` ends in a trailing `:`, an extra empty element is added. And also that an empty `$PATH` is treated as one empty element as it should be.

That approach can't be used for `read` though.

Short of switching to `zsh`, there's no easy work around other than inserting an extra `:` and remove it afterwards like:

```
echo a:b:c: | sed 's/:/::/2' | { IFS=: read -r x y z; z=${z#:}; echo "$z"; }
```

Or (less portable):

```
echo a:b:c: | paste -d: - /dev/null | { IFS=: read -r x y z; z=${z%:}; echo "$z"; }
```

I've also added the `-r` which you generally want when using `read`.

Most likely here [you'd want to use a proper text processing utility like `sed`/`awk`/`perl` instead of writing convoluted and probably inefficient code around `read`](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716) which [has not been designed for that](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184).

---

<sup>¹ Though in the Bourne shell, that was still split into zero elements as there was no distinction between IFS-whitespace and IFS-non-whitespace characters there, something that was also added by ksh</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One "feature" of `read` is that it will [strip leading and trailing **whitespace** separators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/3645) in the variables it populates - it is explained in much more detail at the linked answer. This enables beginners to have `read` do what they expect when doing for example `read first rest <<< ' foo  bar '` (note the extra spaces).

The take-away? It is hard to do *accurate* text processing using Bash and shell tools. If you want full control it's probably better to use a "stricter" language like for example Python, where `split()` will do what you want, but where you might have to dig much deeper into string handling to explicitly remove newline separators or handle encoding.

Comment: Well, then ① why does it not strip the trailing delimiter when there is more than one trailing (e. g. `IFS=: read a b c <<< "A:B:C:D:"; printf "[%s|%s|%s]\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"` →`[A|B|C:D:]`) and ② why is space handled differently than the `:` when `IFS=:` (`IFS=' ' read a b c <<< "A B C D "; printf "[%s|%s|%s]\n" "$a" "$b" "$c"` →`[A|B|C D]`)?